# Visual studio debugging does not work properly

Tags: visual-studio

I encountered a problem while debugging in which the debugger does not work as expected when I press F5 after few seconds when I press pause, I found that stack pointer has not moved at all, environment variables have no changed, and many more signals that the debugger has not finished executing a line of code. In many cases I've seen the debugger stopped at a function entry point (i.e. the bracket '{' of the start).

I need help in figuring how to fix this behaviour since none of my workmates noticed this behaviour in their machines (I am using a machine that was preexisting so I don't have a clue how everything was installed, but the computer works properly and is a powerful one).

I have installed resharper, postsharp, autofac, nhibernate and restsharp at least.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.D: Keep in mind this is a question about the environment, not a programming related question.

Comment: Is it the same line of code in a specific program or is it random?

Comment: By `the bracket '{' of the start` you mean the starting of main function. Is it? And you said it happens so in many cases and not all. So, in other cases, where you do see the debugger breaking at?

Comment: @RBT yeah, the entry point or start of a function, whichever you prefer to call it

Comment: @doctorlove it is random in the meaning that any function I call (this is implemented on a web api service) suddenly stops working and no matter how many times I call the function, it stops at random points of the function, with a prevalence on some more than others

Comment: You should try clearing the debugging symbols by cleaning the solution once. Btw, does the debugger hits your break points if you put any? Or every time the execution just gets lost and you have to press pause button to see the current location of execution of the debugger?

Comment: @RBT The debugger hits any and all breakpoints I put, it's just that request take a lot longer than expected and when I pause to find the current execution instruction being executed.